# how is Billing for Channel API done?

Tags: google-app-engine, billing, channel-api, quotas

I've chosen google-app-engine because of its scalability, and now I try to understand how much I will have to pay once I release the product.

I've looked back and forth in the google app engine documentation to find an answer for question and couldn't find. I found few details in the "Quotas" page, I found how much I can get for free and how much is the Billing Default Quota.

In [Billing Page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/billing.html) there are number for CPU, etc with Resource and Unit and how much it cost. But no where could I find how much will it cost me per channel calls/created, etc.

I can't even try to make calculations with what's in the Admin console, because the current numbers there now are 0 (since there are 2 users which are the programmers).

How can I be ready for the releasing of the product that (hopefully) will have a huge number of channels created daily?

Is there a page I missed, or is there a tool for calculating?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Moishe, thanks for the quick and readable answer. So here are some more questions:
1. Do you think - if needed - that I will be able to get even more quota for the number of channels? I saw there's a special form to ask for more quotas, but I'm not sure that includes the Channel-API feature...
2. Are there any posts you've made for "how to use channel-API efficiently"? I saw some stuff about reusing the tokens per user. Is there more?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating a channel costs about 2.7 CPU-seconds. A CPU-hour costs $0.10. So, each channel created costs

```
(2.7 / 3 600) * $0.10 = $7.5 × 10^-5
```

So creating 1000 channels will cost $0.075, or 7.5 cents.

You'll also get charged the normal outgoing bandwidth costs for any data sent over a channel.

The CPU cost probably isn't the biggest concern; you're more likely to run into quota caps then running out of money. Paid apps are limited to 86400 channel creations/day (1/second).

Comment: Moishe, the news about the limit is very sad for me. But I must say that you are doing a great job! I was expecting that you answer this one, and you did :) thanks for your constant support for this issue's questions...

Comment: Is this answer still true? I'm wondering, because we can create 100 channels per day for free. But I don't find a price for creating more. In the free version creating channels isn't coupled with the CPU cycles (anymore?).